# How do I make Google (search) to index the text in Android app

Tags: android, indexing, google-search

We all know that the Google spider comes by your website now and then to update their database so your website shows up in Google Search.

Is their a way to tell Google all the text I have in my app so it will show the Google Play Store page of my app when a users searches for keywords I use in my app?

I looked into the new Android feature of Google Indexing but those deep-links are something different.

I would like to index the content of my app so it can be found in Google Search before the user knows about and installed my app.

Background info: My app has a lot of (static) textual content in TextViews.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like this that I am aware of.

Google indexes the text you put in the description of your app when you publish it on the Google Play Store.

Take a look at this:

https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/developer-console.html

And here is concrete advise on app discoverability from Google themselves:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4448378?hl=en

Comment: Thanks, I've already took care about that. The thing is.,. There are way more keywords in the TextViews in my app as I can put on the Play Store page so I was hoping there is way to include those.